# Why I cannot fix KDE sound?

Tags: audio, kde, settings

After I unplugged my microphone, KDE switched my `Built-in Audio` Sound card to a `GK106 HDMI Audio Controller` that does not work (no HDMI). If I run 
`System  Settings > Multimedia > Audio and Video > Audio Hardware setup`
I can change the GK106 to the `Built-in Audio` (and APPLY), and sound works fine. But if I log out and log in again, Sound again does not work, and the setting shows again `GK106 HDMI Audio Controller`. In fact, after closing the settings and open it again, I see `GK106 HDMI Audio Controller`...

Any clues how to fix this?

Fully updated Fedora 26 with KDE spin running here.

Comment: Did you try changing the priority of the various devices in `System  Settings > Multimedia > Audio and Video > Device Preference`?

Comment: @bu5hman: That's also weird. I see 4 devices, 3 of them grayed out (in particular, the two in the "Audio Hardware setup" tab), except "Dummy Output". BTW, my problems began when I unplugged a microphone. I use Linux since Redhat 2, and it never ever had a solid audio management, always full of bugs.... :/

Comment: I've often had issues with audio too. A few things to investigate: `pavucontrol`, `alsamixer`, and `pulseaudio -k`.

Comment: Adding the line `pactl set-card-profile 1 output:analog-stereo` into the `.xinitrc` file restored the audio. It was definitely fixed only when I plugged back the microphone (???).